# Matching Part of a String in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I would like to make a query which matches a string, either completely or partially.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT code 
FROM jos_rsticketspro_tickets
WHERE message LIKE '%1. Fuente Dorada%';
```

The solution would match message contents "*fuente*". "*fuen*". "*orada*". "*1. Fuente Dorada*", etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use full-text searching?

Comment: you are going beyond the capabilities of the `LIKE` syntax. Next step is `FULLTEXT`, but with the matches you want to have I reckon you're probably past that too. A tool like Sphinx should be able to do it but may be overkill for you. Maybe you should just set up a table of tags? That would be easier to search in.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work. it will check row wich have `message` part of `"1. Fuente Dorada"`

```
SELECT code 
FROM jos_rsticketspro_tickets
WHERE "1. Fuente Dorada" LIKE concat("%", message, "%");
```